# how to convert string into an integer in a batch file ?

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2010, batch-file, pre-build-event

I have this piece of batch file :

```
@echo off
set  xx=7
echo the version is %xx%
```

I wand to use it in a pre-build event in VS2010 - as an integer :

```
MY_INT = $(xx)
```

but it's value is a string , how can I convert the string value into an integer value in the batch file?

thanks!

Comment: How does this pertain to C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Environment variables (batch variables) are always strings; they cannot be stored as integers.

The SET command with the /A option can parse integral numbers from strings, perform arithmetic operations, and store the integral result in an environment variable. But the final result is still a string representation of the final number.

Type `help set` or `set /?` from a command prompt for more info about the SET /A option.

Comment: thanks! it there a way to define environment varaibles using .bat file? how can I do it?

Comment: @user1386966 - Umm... That is what the SET command is for. I said as much already in the answer.

Comment: Watch out for **set /A SomeVariable = 08** or  **set /A SomeVariable = 09**
Batch treats 0 prefixed numbers as Octal instead of decimal.
check [this link](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntset.php)